# Connection actively refused

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, connection

I'm writing a C# Sockets network application. *It worked perfectly while I was testing by connecting to the server on "127.0.0.1"*, but when I got to the point where I decided that I want to test from other machines and switched the address of the connection to my actual IP address, I started getting the

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it -my IP address:port-

exception.

I was looking for solutions in other posts, one I found was to **disable my firewall**, but that didn't solve the problem.

The ports do match in the client and the server, so that's not the issue.

Another post suggested to run `netstat -anb` and see if the server is listening on the specified port, and to my surprise the application didn't even show up among the results.

Here's the code for establishing the connection:

The connection method from my class that deals with the connection on the client side:

```
public bool Connect()
            {
            if (!connected)
                {
                try
                    {
                    sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    sock.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port));
                    connected = true;
                    return true;
                    }
                catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    connected = false;
                    return false;
                    }
                }
            return false;
            }
```

Server side I use this simple listener:

```
public class Listener
        {
        Socket sock;
        bool listening = false;
        int port;

        public delegate void socketAcceptedHandler(Socket s);
        public event socketAcceptedHandler socketAccepted;

        public Listener(int port)
            {
            this.port = port;
            }

        public void start()
            {
            if (listening)
                {
                return;
                }

            sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, port));
            sock.Listen(0);
            sock.BeginAccept(callback, null);

            listening = true;
            }

        public void stop()
            {
            if (!listening)
                {
                return;
                }

            if (sock != null)
                {
                sock.Close();
                sock.Dispose();
                }

            listening = false;
            }

        public void callback(IAsyncResult result)
            {
            try
                {
                Socket s = sock.EndAccept(result);

                if (socketAccepted != null)
                    {
                    socketAccepted(s);
                    }

                sock.BeginAccept(callback, null);
                }
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong:\n{0}", e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE:
I checked if the connection is established if I use my local IP address, it is. Must be a router thing.

Comment: Try to set `sock.Listen(0)` to `sock.Listen(1)` so u allow at least 1 connection.

Comment: During the localhost tests I managed to connect to the server with multiple clients at the same time, I think 0 might mean "use the OS limit".

Comment: The net library will always give an error if you attempt to connect the client to the loopback address 127.0.0.1.  Instead connect to the IP of the computer.

Comment: No, it won't. If you just read the OP you'd have seen that I tested the program out connecting to 127.0.0.1 and it worked perfectly fine that way.

Answer (score 1):

A firewall could be blocking the port, some other program could be listening on the port or the port is restricted. You can run "netstat -aon" at command prompt to see which process is listening on the port you want to access.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. As I stated in the OP the firewall is disabled and the port specified in the code does not even show up in netstat.

Comment: Try adding a static host entry on the client machine.

Comment: I don't know what that is or how to add it. Can you explain please?

Comment: Navigate to the directory C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc . There you have a file called HOSTS. You can add hostname and IP address there.

Comment: Okay, I'm there.

Comment: Chiran solution will only solve the issue if you are trying to connect to localhost and the local host is missing or configured wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As per the edit: since it works with my local address I assume it must be a router thing, most likely I just need for forward the port. If that doesn't turn out to be the answer I'll repost, but for now I'd like to thank everybody who commented, and treat this as the solution.